# Определение принадлежности координат к полигону YMaps.Polygon.contains()

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть задача определить принадлежность точки к полигону. Мануалы читал. Работает в коде всё, кроме метода `contains()`.

Вот код:

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(init);
// ------------ Рисуем карту ----------------------------------
 function init() {myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 9,
   controls: []
        });          // Всё ОК, карта нарисовалась
// ---------- Определяем полигон ------------------------------

  var myPolygon = new ymaps.Polygon([
   [
    [55.779925, 37.842169], 
    [55.578971, 37.695932], 
    [55.709596, 37.389032],
    [55.905406, 37.528244]
   ]
  ]);
  myPolygon.options.set('visible', false); // Тут всё хорошо
  
// ---------- Добавляем на карту ------------------------------

  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPolygon);  // Полигон нарисовался
  
// ---------- Новое событие на карте --------------------------
  
  myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {  //   Клик по карте
   var coords=e.get('coords');     // Определяем координаты клика
   alert(coords[0].toPrecision(6)+' '+coords[1].toPrecision(6)); // Выводим себе на посмотреть, всё ОК
   if (myPolygon.contains(coords[0],coords[1])) {alert('Попал!');} // А вот тут не работает ни хрена!!!!
  });
 }
 </script>
```

Что не так и как надо?

В песочницу не посылайте, там я был.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для определения попадания точки в полигон не обязательно добавлять его на карту, главное выставить родителя, т.е. корректно задать карту, которой принадлежит полигон.

В документацию закралась ошибка, исправим.

```js
  ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.76, 37.64],
    zoom: 9,
    controls: []
  }); 

//ромб над Москвой
var myPolygon = new ymaps.Polygon([
    [
      [55.779925, 37.842169],
      [55.578971, 37.695932],
      [55.709596, 37.389032],
      [55.905406, 37.528244]
    ]
  ]);

myPolygon.options.setParent(myMap.options);
myPolygon.geometry.setMap(myMap);

// Проверка, входит ли точка клика в полигон, с заданной выше геометрией.
myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
    alert(myPolygon.geometry.contains(e.get('coords')) ? 'Попал!' : 'Мимо!');
});
}
```

```css
html, body, #map {
            width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Премного благодарен! Сейчас попробую. Этот пример в песочнице я видел, правда, он у меня тоже не заработал... Ща попробую ещё раз