# Вхождение координат в окружность

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Есть задача - нужно выяснить, входят ли координаты из массива JSON в окружность. Почему то некоторые точки помечает как не входящие, хотя даже наглядно видно что лежат в окружности. Вот так определяется окружность.

```
var bounds = new ymaps.Circle([[my_bounds.y, my_bounds.x], my_bounds.radius], {}, 
{        // Опции.
    // Цвет и прозрачность заливки.
    fillColor: '#7df9ff33',
    // Дополнительная прозрачность заливки..
    // Итоговая прозрачность будет не #33(0.2), а 0.1(0.2*0.5).
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    // Цвет обводки.
    strokeColor: '#0000FF',
    // Прозрачность обводки.
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    // Ширина линии.
    strokeWidth: 2,
    // Радиус скругления углов.
    // Данная опция принимается только прямоугольником.
    borderRadius: 0,
    geodesic: true
});
myMap.geoObjects.add(bounds);
```

и вот так потом перебирается массив с точками

```
$(json.features).each(function(i, e) {
  if(bounds.geometry.contains(e.geometry.coordinates) == false) {
    lost.push(e);
    delete json.features[i];
  }
});
PipleObjectManager.add(json);
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Определение принадлежности координат к полигону YMaps.Polygon.contains()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785449/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%83-ymaps-polygon-contains)

Comment: Покажите конкретные данные на которых проявляется ошибка

Comment: координаты центра круга, город Данилов
x: 40.171419,
y: 58.186047,
radius: 5000,

улица Вологодская, дом 12 - говорит что не лежит в окружности

Answer (score 1):

```
$(json.features).each(function(i, e) {
  if(bounds.geometry.contains(e.geometry.coordinates) == false) {
    lost.push(e);
    delete json.features[i];
```

Вы при обходе массива/списка `json.features` меняете его. Это вообще законно? :)

Если есть такая возможность - обходите массив с конца.

Comment: Даже если не удалять элементы массива, а просто в консоль логировать - все равно не понятно почему помечает точки как не входящие, если даже визуально видно что они в окружности :)

Comment: Вы можете вручную контролировать - выводить также расчёт руками - квадрат расстояния до центра должен быть меньше квадрата радиуса. Возможно, это поможет идентифицировать ошибку